# Counting the frequency of bases using while loop and substr with Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write in Perl to count the number of each A/C/G/T bases in a DNA sequence. But couldn't figure out what went wrong in my code. "ATCTAGCTAGCTAGCTA" is the kind of data I am given.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file = <$ARGV[0]>;
open( my $FH_IN, "<", $in_file );

my $dna   = <$FH_IN>;
my $index = 0;
my ( $freq_a, $freq_c, $freq_g, $freq_t ) = 0;

my $dna_length = length($dna);
while ( $index < $dna_length ) {
    my $base = substr( $dna, $index, 1 );
    if ( $base eq "A" ) {
        $freq_a++;
        $index++;
        next;
    } elsif ( $base eq "C" ) {
        $freq_c++;
        $index++;
        next;
    } elsif ( $base eq "G" ) {
        $freq_g++;
        $index++;
        next;
    } elsif ( $base eq "T" ) {
        $freq_t++;
        $index++;
        next;
    } else {
        next;
    }
}
print "$freq_a\n$freq_c\n$freq_g\n$freq_t\n";

exit;
```

I know there are a lot of ways to do it, but what I want to know is what I did wrong so I can learn from mistakes.

Comment: Have you read the comments I made on your previous script? Some of the same issues pop up in this one. You should also post some information about what is going wrong. How are you handling multiple lines in your in file?

Comment: Thank you for your previous clarification, I got the "next", "or die" and "$index++" parts in your previous answer. But I am still trying to think what went wrong in this one. Is the concept of my code wrong or the syntax? My data file is just a long single string of DNA sequence. When I run this code, I got nothing as output but I was told there was a process still running when I attempted to close the tab

Comment: This is rather inefficient code. Why not use a hash to count instead? `while ($dna =~ /([ACGT])/g) { $count{$1}++ }` would replace almost all your code.

Comment: I still haven't learn hash yet, I am trying to do this question after the end of my class on flow control.

Comment: Well, first of all `my $in_file= <$ARGV[0]>;` is not a valid statement. You don't put the file name in `<>`, that's only when reading from a file handle. A file handle is what you get when using `open`.

Comment: But `<$ARGV[0]>` works (accidentally) here, as perl interprets it as t he globbing operator :-/ It is, of course, unnecessary though.

Comment: I still couldn't get any output after I get rid of the <>

Comment: In your `else` condition you do not increase the `$index`, so you get an infinite loop (because you have a newline at the end of the line).

Comment: You can reuse the command line args / file open / line chomping code that you wrote in your last script to solve the problem with the `<>`.

Comment: It works this time, I am still trying to digest and understand this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you've done well so far and there's only one problem that stops your program from working.

It's far from obvious, but each line that's read from the file has a newline character `"\n"` at the end. So what's happening is that `$index` reaches the newline in the string, which is processed by the `else` clause (because it's not `A`, `C`, `G` or `T`) which just does a `next`, so the same character is processed over and over again. Your program just hangs, right?

You could remove the newline with `chomp`, but a proper fix is to increment `$index` in the `else` clause just as you do with all the other characters. So it looks like

```
else {
   ++$index;
   next;
}
```

As you've suspected, there are much better ways to write this. There are also a couple of other nasties in your code, but that change should get you on your way for now.

Comment: @zebra: Good. You may want to try [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you have any other questions. You'll probably find them a little less harsh than Stack Overflow or [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), that are meant for professional programmers with specific bugs they can't iron out. Take a look and see which suits you.

Answer (score 2):

Perl has a special file handle to use with these kinds of problems: The diamond operator `<>`. It will read input from either a file name, if provided, and standard input if not.

Secondly, since you are only interested in `ACGT`, might as well look for only them, using a regex: `/([ACGT])/g`.

Thirdly, using a hash is the idiomatic way to count characters in Perl: `$count{A}++`

So your script becomes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count;
while (<>) {
    while (/([ACGT])/g) {
        $count{$1}++;
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @count{qw(A C G T)};
```

Usage:

```
script.pl input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be instructive for you to print out the values in `$dna_length`, `$index` and `$base` each time you go round the loop - immediately after you assign a value to `$base`.

Your code would be more robust if you moved the incrementing of `$index` to the end of the loop (outside of the `if`/`elsif`/`else` block) and removed all of your `next` statements.

An alternative "quick fix" is to `chomp()` the input line before you start processing it.