# Counting the frequencies of bases using for loop and substr in perl

Tags: perl, for-loop, substr

I'm trying to count the number of bases using a for loop and the substr function but the counts are off and I'm not sure why! Please help! I have to use these functions in my assignment. Where am I going wrong? Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $user_input = "accgtutf5";

#initalizing the lengths
my $a_base_total = 0;
my $c_base_total = 0;
my $g_base_total = 0;
my $t_base_total = 0;
my $other_total  = 0;

for ( my $position = 0; $position < length $user_input; $position++ ) {
    my $nucleotide = substr( $user_input, $position, 1 );
    if ( $nucleotide eq "a" ) {
        $a_base_total++;
    } elsif ( $nucleotide eq "c" ) {
        $c_base_total++;
    } elsif ( $nucleotide eq "g" ) {
        $g_base_total++;
    } elsif ( $nucleotide eq "t" ) {
        $t_base_total++;
    } else {
        $other_total++;
    }
    $position++;
}

print "a = $a_base_total\n";
print "c = $c_base_total\n";
print "g = $g_base_total\n";
print "t = $t_base_total\n";
print "other = $other_total\n";
```

The output I'm getting is :

```
a=1
c=1
g=0
t=2
other=1
```

When it should be:

```
a = 1
c = 2
g = 1
t = 2
other = 3
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting the frequency of bases using while loop and substr with Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191017/counting-the-frequency-of-bases-using-while-loop-and-substr-with-perl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing twice.

Simply remove this line:

```
$position++;
```

Also, instead of iterating on position, I would suggest iterating on character.

Your script can be simplified to just:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $user_input = "accgtutf5";

my %count;

for my $nucleotide (split '', $user_input) {
    $nucleotide = 'other' unless $nucleotide =~ /[acgt]/;
    $count{$nucleotide}++;
}

printf "%s = %d\n", $_, $count{$_} // 0 for qw(a c g t other);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing $position twice: once at the `for` and once at the end of the loop. Remove the second `$position++`.